# To whom the Election applied according to the Calvinist (TULIP)?

Tags: reformed-theology, predestination, unconditional-election

A. To every human (including Adam and Eve) who will exist in the future.
B. To every human (except Adam and Eve) who will exist in the future.
C. To every human who will exist in the future after Jesus ascended to heaven.
D. (if not A/B/C)

In detail :
A. Once Adam and Eve exist on earth (and all the rest of their generation), the possibility for them are :
- they are all the elected one (absolutely go to heaven)
- none of them are the elected one (absolutely go to hell)
- some of them are the elected one

B. That kind of possibility applied only to Adam's generation. 
For example : once baby Cain/Abel/Seth (Adam and Eve not included, but the rest of their generation) were born.

C. That kind of possibility applied only to Adam's generation who will be born after Jesus ascended to heaven
For example : assuming there are 10 babies were born at the same time soon after Jesus ascended to heaven, then the possibility on these babies after they die (even if they die after a few days)  are :
- all of these 10 babies will go to heaven (all are the elected one)
- all of these 10 babies will go to hell (none of them is the elected one)
- some of them will go to heaven, the rest to hell (some of them are the elected one

Comment: It's A. Did you see someone suggest it was B or C?

Comment: @curiousdannii, In our language Christian Forum, I read that it's C. Apply to only the one who will be able to become Christian (Jesus follower).

Comment: That's definitely not Calvinism/Reformed Theology. The [Westminster Confession says it well](http://www.reformed.org/documents/wcf_with_proofs/index.html?body=/documents/wcf_with_proofs/ch_III.html): 3.1 "God from all eternity, did, by the most wise and holy counsel of His own will, freely, and unchangeably ordain whatsoever comes to pass; yet so, as thereby neither is God the author of sin, nor is violence offered to the will of the creatures; nor is the liberty or contingency of second causes taken away, but rather established."

Comment: @curiousdannii, oke - I will let him know about this. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

God’s Sovereign Election applies to every human being ever born.  That does not mean that every human being ever born will be saved, and universal salvation is not supported within the Five Points of Calvinism.  God’s election means that from before the founding of the world God had predestined whom He would call and that God foreknew who the elect would be.

As far back as the 5th century the basic doctrines of the Calvinistic position had been vigorously defended by Augustine against Pelagius.   The five points of Calvinism (formulated in answer to the five points submitted by the Arminians) was ratified by the Synod of Dort in 1619. Here are a few partial quotes from the book, The Five Points of Calvinism by David N. Steele and Curtis C. Thomas, by Presbyterian and Reformed Publishing in 1963:

> UNCONDITIONAL ELECTION (pages 16-17): “God’s choice of certain individuals unto salvation before the foundation of the world rested solely in His own sovereign will...  God gives faith and repentance to each individual whom He selected...  Thus God’s choice of the sinner, not the sinner’s choice of Christ, is the ultimate cause of salvation.”
>
> PARTICULAR REDEMTION OR LIMITED ATONEMENT (page 17): “Christ’s redeeming work was intended to save the elect only and actually secured salvation for them.  His death was a substitutionary endurance of the penalty of sin in the place of certain specified sinners.”
>
> LIMITED ATONEMENT (pages 53-54): “The gospel invitation extends a general outward call to salvation to all who hear the message.  In addition to the external call, the Holy Spirit extends a special inward call to the elect only.  The general call of the gospel can be, and often is, rejected, but the special call of the Spirit cannot be rejected; it always results in the conversion of those to whom it was made.”
>
> “All those whom God hath predestinated unto life, and those only, is he pleased in his appointed and  accepted time, effectually to call by his word and Spirit, out of that state of sin and death in which they are by nature, to grace and salvation by Jesus Christ.” (The Westminster Confession of Faith, Chapter 10, Section 1)

Some the Scriptures used to support these beliefs include Romans 1:6-7; 8:30; 9:23-24; Galatians 1:15-16; Ephesians 4:4; 2 Timothy 1:9; Hebrews 9:15; Jude verse 1.  Regarding the role of the Holy Spirit in the work of salvation see Romans 8:14; 1 Corinthians 12:3; 1 Peter 1:2; John 1:12-13.

Not everyone is elected unto salvation.  I hope this helps to clarify the Calvinistic view of Election.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Lesley. You wrote : _"God’s Sovereign Election applies to every human being ever **born**"_. So, it's B. I wonder what about Adam and Eve as they are created not born.

Comment: Please do not presume to interpret the meaning of my words.  I disagree with  the manner in which you present election because many of your basic premises are flawed. I would not dare to presume whether God elected Adam and Eve to salvation - or not. I have merely attempted to offer a simple explanation to show that God has the divine right to elect those whom he pleases unto salvation.

Comment: I'm not asking whether God elected Adam and Eve to salvation - or not, Lesley. What I'm asking is whether the election took place after Adam and Eve ate the fruit or before they haven't done anything.

Comment: @karma - It was before Adam and Eve did anything.  What they did was known to God before they did it. The same is true of everything else in the Universe.  God knows everything that will ever happen before the foundation of the world.  God chose his elect to be saved before He created the Universe.  This order of events is to help us understand - with God there is no time.